# Where are the images temporarily stored after upload?

Tags: asp.net

I am not much of a programmer, so I apologize for any lack of understanding in this issue that I may have. I have been digging through all of the code, but I cannot figure this one out. 
The site is an asp.net site. No errors while compiling except about height, which does not apply. I am using a shared host, so I have no access to system files.

A customer uploads an image to our site for us to process and print whatever products they order. The image does not appear anywhere on the server until they hit the proceed to payment button. I have downloaded the entire site before and after to verify folder size.

Where is the image temporarily stored before it is actually stored as a .jpg?

```
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button CssClass="Buttons" ID="Button1" 
        style="font-weight: bold; color: white; background-color: #336699;" 
        runat="server" OnClick="AddToCartButton_Click" 
        Text="Upload Image and Add To Cart" 
        CommandArgument="ObjectDataSourceEventArgs" />
&nbsp; 
<div style="width:800px">
    <br />
    Larger files may take a minute or two to upload
    <asp:Label ID="lblLimitReached" runat="server" 
        Visible="false" STYLE="color:Red" Text="">
    </asp:Label>
</div>
<br /><hr /><br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="Solid"
    Caption="Shopping Cart" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="ShoppingCartDataSource"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical" CaptionAlign="Top" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalImageName" HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="OriginalImageName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SizePrice" HeaderText="Size / Price" SortExpression="SizePrice" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MountedString" HeaderText="Mounted" SortExpression="Mounted" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DigitalString" HeaderText="Digital Frame" SortExpression="DigitalFrame" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BWString" HeaderText="Black &amp; White" SortExpression="BlackAndWhite" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PriceString" HeaderText="Price" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PriceString" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ShoppingCartDataSource" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="ImageInfo"
    DeleteMethod="DeleteData" InsertMethod="InsertData" SelectMethod="SelectData"
    TypeName="ImageInfoCollection" UpdateMethod="UpdateData" OnObjectCreating="ShoppingCartDataSource_ObjectCreating" ></asp:ObjectDataSource>
<hr /><br />
<asp:Label ID="TotalPriceLabel" runat="server" style="display:inline" Text="Current total: $0.00" Width="162px"></asp:Label>
    <br />
<asp:Button CssClass="Buttons" ID="CheckOutButton" runat="server" 
    Text="Go To Check Out" CausesValidation="False" 
    OnClick="PlaceOrderButton_Click" 
    style="font-weight: bold; color: white; background-color: #336699;" 
    Visible="False" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="FreeShipLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF0033"></asp:Label><br />
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="ImageSizeDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/ImageSizeData.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ImagePathValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
    ErrorMessage="Please select an image to upload." Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="FileUploadTypeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
    Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please upload only files of type jpg (or jpeg)."
    ValidationExpression="(.*\.jpg)|(.*\.jpeg)|(.*\.JPG)|(.*\.JPEG)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ImageSizeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="SizeDropDownList"
    ErrorMessage="Please select an image size." Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuantityValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="QuantityTextBox"
    ErrorMessage="Please select image quantity." Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="QuantityExpressionValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="QuantityTextBox"
    Display="None" ErrorMessage="Invalid quantity: please choose 1 to 999." ValidationExpression="^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="List"
    HeaderText="Something is missing:" Height="40px" ShowMessageBox="True"
    ShowSummary="False" Width="179px" />
<br />
<div style="width:800px">
    <uc3:Footer ID="Footer1" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
```

This is the buynow.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml; 
using System.Drawing;

public partial class BuyNow : System.Web.UI.Page
{
const string DFText = "Choose a Digital Frame.";

/// <summary>
/// Page_Load
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page PP = Page.PreviousPage as ASP.home_aspx;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ImageInfoCollection ImageInfo = new ImageInfoCollection();
        Session["ImageInfoCollection"] = ImageInfo;
        ResetDefaults();
        FreeShipLabel.Text = "";
        FileUpload1.Focus();
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// AddToCartButton_Click
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void AddToCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ImageInfoCollection Images = (ImageInfoCollection)Session["ImageInfoCollection"];
    if (Images == null) {
        Session["SessionError"] = "No Images on BuyNow->AddToCartButton_Click";
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
    }


    if (Images.Count >= 20)
    {
        lblLimitReached.Text = "Only 20 Images allowed per order...Please place another order";
        lblLimitReached.Visible = true;
        return;
    }
    /// BUG: need to figure out how to handle the Back Button case

    if (DigitalFramesCheckBox.Checked && (DigitalFrameLabel.Text == "" || DigitalFrameLabel.Text == DFText))
        return;

    ImageInfo Image = CreateImageInfoFromPage();
    if (Image == null)
        return;

    Images.InsertData(Image);
    Session["ImageInfoCollection"] = Images;
    ShoppingCartDataSource.Select();

    GridView1.DataBind(); // update the GridView shopping cart
    TotalPriceLabel.Text = "Current Total: " + CalculateCartPrice(Images);
    ResetDefaults();

    if (Images.FreeShipping())
        FreeShipLabel.Text = "Order Qualifies for Free Shipping.";
    else
        FreeShipLabel.Text = "";

    if (Images.Count > 0)
        CheckOutButton.Visible = true;

}


/// <summary>
/// ShoppingCartDataSource_ObjectCreating
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void ShoppingCartDataSource_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    ImageInfoCollection Images = (ImageInfoCollection)Session["ImageInfoCollection"];
    if (Images == null) {
        Session["SessionError"] = "No Images on ShoppingCartDataSource_ObjectCreating";
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
    }

    e.ObjectInstance = Images;
}

/// <summary>
/// GridView1_RowDeleting
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    ImageInfoCollection Images = (ImageInfoCollection)Session["ImageInfoCollection"];
    if (Images == null)
        return;

    Images.DeleteData(e.RowIndex);
    Session["ImageInfoCollection"] = Images;

    TotalPriceLabel.Text = "Current Total: " + CalculateCartPrice(Images);

    if (Images.FreeShipping())
        FreeShipLabel.Text = "Order Qualifies for Free Shipping.";
    else
        FreeShipLabel.Text = "";

    if (Images.Count == 0)
        CheckOutButton.Visible = false;
}

/// <summary>
/// SizeDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void SizeDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // read the xml file to determine image size attributes
    int index = SizeDropDownList.SelectedIndex;
    ImageXmlAttributes Attrs = new ImageXmlAttributes(ImageSizeDataSource);
    Attrs.LoadByIndex(index);

    // translate the attributes into controls for the page
    // QuantityListBox.Text = Convert.ToString(Attrs.Quantity);
    if (Attrs.MountingAvailable) {
        MountingCheckBox.Enabled = true;
        MountingPriceLabel.Enabled = true;
        MountingPriceLabel.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(Attrs.MountingPrice);
    }
    else  {
        MountingCheckBox.Enabled = false;
        MountingCheckBox.Checked = false;
        MountingPriceLabel.Enabled = false;
        MountingPriceLabel.Text = "";
    }

    if (Attrs.DigitalAvailable) {
        DigitalFramesCheckBox.Enabled = true;
        DigitalFrameLabel.Text = "";
    }
    else {
        DigitalFramesCheckBox.Enabled = false;
        DigitalFramesCheckBox.Checked = false;
        DigitalFramePanel.Visible = false;
        DigitalFrameLabel.Text = "";
    }

    if (Attrs.BWAvailable)
        BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Enabled = true;
    else {
        BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Enabled = false;
        BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Checked = false;
    }

    CardPanel.Visible = false;

    if ((SizeDropDownList.Text == "DLCCU1") || (SizeDropDownList.Text == "DLCCU2") || (SizeDropDownList.Text == "DLCCU3"))
    {
        CardPanel.Visible = true;
     }
}

protected void MountingCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!MountingCheckBox.Checked)
        MountingPriceLabel.Text = "";
    else {
        // read the xml file to determine image size attributes
        int index = SizeDropDownList.SelectedIndex;
        ImageXmlAttributes Attrs = new ImageXmlAttributes(ImageSizeDataSource);
        Attrs.LoadByIndex(index);
        MountingPriceLabel.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(Attrs.MountingPrice);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// PlaceOrderButton_Click
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void PlaceOrderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/CustomerInfo.aspx");
}

/// <summary>
/// CreateImageFromPage
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private ImageInfo CreateImageInfoFromPage()
{
    ImageInfo Image = new ImageInfo( ImageSizeDataSource );
    Image.MyFileUpload = FileUpload1;
    Image.OriginalImageName = FileUpload1.FileName; 
    Image.Mounted = MountingCheckBox.Checked;
    Image.BlackAndWhite = BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Checked;

    Image.DigitalFrame = DigitalFramesCheckBox.Checked;
    Image.DigitalFrameID = DigitalFrameLabel.Text;

    Image.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTextBox.Text);
    Image.LoadAttributes(SizeDropDownList.SelectedIndex);
    return Image;
}

/// <summary>
/// ResetDefaults
/// </summary>
private void ResetDefaults()
{
    SizeDropDownList.ClearSelection();
    QuantityTextBox.Text = "1";
    MountingCheckBox.Checked = false;
    MountingPriceLabel.Text = "";
    MountingCheckBox.Enabled = true;
    BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Checked = false;
    BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Enabled = true;
    DigitalFramesCheckBox.Checked = false;
    DigitalFramesCheckBox.Enabled = true;
    DigitalFramePanel.Visible = false;
    CardPanel.Visible = false;
    CardPanel.Visible = false;
    DigitalFrameLabel.Text = "";
    DigitalFrameLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}

/// <summary>
/// CalculateCartPrice
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Images"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static string CalculateCartPrice(ImageInfoCollection Images)
{
    return Images.GetTotalPriceString();
}

protected void DigitalFramesCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TurnOffAllRadioButtons();
    if (DigitalFramesCheckBox.Checked == true) {
        DigitalFramePanel.Visible = true;
        DigitalFrameLabel.Text = DFText;
        DigitalFrameLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        SizeDropDownList.SelectedValue = "DL20U";
        BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Checked = false;
        BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Enabled = false;
    }
    else {
        DigitalFramePanel.Visible = false;
        DigitalFrameLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        DigitalFrameLabel.Text = "";
        SizeDropDownList.SelectedValue = "";
        BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Checked = false;
        BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Enabled = true;
    }
}

protected void RadioButtonF1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF1, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF2, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF3, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF4, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF5, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF6, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF7, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF8_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF8, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF9_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF9, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF13_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF13, e);
}

protected void RadioButton15_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF15, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF16_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF16, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF17_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF17, e);
}

protected void RadioButtonF18_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectRadioButton(RadioButtonF18, e);
}

private void SelectRadioButton(RadioButton RB, EventArgs e)
{
    TurnOffAllRadioButtons();
    RB.Checked = true;
    DigitalFrameLabel.Text = RB.ToolTip;
    DigitalFrameLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}

private void TurnOffAllRadioButtons()
{
    RadioButtonF1.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF2.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF3.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF4.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF5.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF6.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF7.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF8.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF9.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF1.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF13.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF15.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF16.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF17.Checked = false;
    RadioButtonF18.Checked = false;
}

protected void BlackAndWhiteCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (BlackAndWhiteCheckBox.Checked) {
        DigitalFramesCheckBox.Checked = false;
        DigitalFramesCheckBox.Enabled = false;
    }
    else {
        if ((SizeDropDownList.SelectedValue == "DL20U") || (SizeDropDownList.SelectedValue == ""))
        {
            DigitalFramesCheckBox.Enabled = true;
            DigitalFramesCheckBox.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines are the problem:

```
    Images.InsertData(Image);
    Session["ImageInfoCollection"] = Images;
    ShoppingCartDataSource.Select();
```

Basically, when the images are uploaded they are being stored in the session object.  This means it is going straight into the web servers RAM and staying there.  This is a very bad idea, especially for servers expecting any type of load.  The reason, incidentally, for why it's bad is that it results in massively increased RAM usage AND if the web app needs to recycle (which is very likely to happen often in this situation) then all images stored in session will be lost.

This needs to be changed to either push the images to the database or to a temporary file on disk.  Either way, how this is coded means you will not see any files show up on the file system until they are moved from Session to disk.

Comment: The website is https://www.digilarge.com/ If you try uploading an image, make sure it is a large one so you can notice when it is actually uploading.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. Would you be willing to offer me a fix for this? Send me a message privately if you like. chris at portrait express dot com

Comment: @Computationalerr: I appreciate the request, but I don't do contract stuff anymore (have my own company).  I answer questions here simply for fun.  However, I'd say most devs ought to be able to figure this out and handle it correctly.  BTW, just an off the cuff analysis, I'd say you're looking at anywhere between 40 and 80 hours to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

When you use a control like the file upload, the uploaded file gets placed in a temp folder somewhere on the web application's server.  Where it gets placed really doesn't matter because asp.net provided you with an object to use.  For example:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="position: static" Width="255px"  />
<asp:Button ID="Uploadbtn" runat="server" OnClick="Uploadbtn_Click" Style="position: static" Text="Upload" Width="82px" />
```

This control creates the typical upload control.  It has a browse button and an upload button.  When the user clicks the upload button, you would have an event method like this:

```
Protected Sub Uploadbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Dim myUploadeObject As HttpPostedFile
   myUploadeObject = Me.FileUpload.PostedFile       
End Sub
```

The HttpPostedFile objects has a whole bunch of methods and properties you can access, like the file name, the inputs stream, content type and length.

Furthermore, the fileUPload object itself has many useful properties and methods like:  HasFile, File Name, file bytes, and contents

Bring them together and you can do something like this:

```
 Protected Sub Uploadbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim fu As FileUpload
    fu = Me.FileUpload

    If (fu.HasFile = True) Then
        Dim myUploadeObject As HttpPostedFile
        myUploadeObject = Me.FileUpload.PostedFile

        Dim filePath As String = myUploadeObject.FileName
        Dim fileName As String = fu.FileName
        Dim fileBytes As Byte() = fu.FileBytes
        Dim fileContenetType As String = myUploadeObject.ContentType
        Dim inputStream As IO.FileStream = myUploadeObject.InputStream

    Else
        'there was a problem, alert the user
    End If      
End Sub
```